# What is the piano song playing in Sekaiichi Hatsukoi 2, episode 2 when Takano and Onodera viewed the snow scene?

Tags: music, sekai-ichi-hatsukoi

In season 2 episode 2 of *Sekai Ichi Hatsukoi* at around 15:31, there's a piano song playing when Takano and Onodera viewed the snow scene.

It sounds familiar, and I just want to make sure.

What is this song?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know which song you're talking about. Looking through the OST for season two helped me. I found out that maybe track 6 is the one you're looking for? It's called, " Shunjun suru Kimochi."

You can check for yourself [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmeZQPyud38&list=PL4D947035A6EAC0C7&index=6).

Although I didn't think that scene has a piano.

But if my suggestion is wrong, the link I provided has the full OST on the playlist. Also, the person's channel has other Sekaiichi Hatsukoi OSTs, you can try your luck there ^^